# Move spinner from fagment to activity given NullPointerException

Tags: android-fragments, android-activity, spinner

I try to move some fragment code to activity in my android code apps, but I found the trouble with the spinner.

My activity codes

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
    // Spinner element
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerCari);
    edt = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.edtCari);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
    String itemKategori = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    // Showing selected spinner item
    //Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + itemKategori, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    loadAutoComplateData(itemKategori);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
    {

    }
    });

}
```

Error result :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.erlanggastudio.myagri, PID: 11839
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.erlanggastudio.myagri/com.erlanggastudio.myagri.activities.ActivityCariPestisida}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemSelectedListener)' on a null object reference
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2465)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2530)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:163)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1358)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1397)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1192)
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemSelectedListener)' on a null object reference
      at com.erlanggastudio.myagri.activities.ActivityCariPestisida.onCreate(ActivityCariPestisida.java:43)
```

Comment: can you please paste `activity_profile` xml

Comment: I think you forgot to move the UI components from the fragment to the activity layout file :)  Just review your layout

Comment: ok yup...i forget the xml layout....not activity_profile.xml.....